# Tricky jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="image-widget-data"><span class="file">
    <input type="hidden" value="115" name="field_tablica[und][0][fid]">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="field_tablica[und][0][display]">
    <input type="hidden" value="560" name="field_tablica[und][0][width]">
    <input type="hidden" value="560" name="field_tablica[und][0][height]">
    <div class="imageeditor">
        <div class="editors">
            <div data-codename="picmonkey" 
                 title="PicMonkey" 
                 class="imageeditor-widget-item picmonkey imageeditor-processed">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When clicking on DIV.picmonkey I would like to get value "115" from input named `field_tablica[und][0][fid]` where 0 can be from 0 to 9.

What jQuery selector should I use?

Comment: Show your jQuery code. Might guide you: `$('div[data-codename="picmonkey"]').closest('.image-widget-data').find('input[name="field_tablica[und][0][fid]]').val()`

Comment: `var value = $(this).closest('.image-widget-data').find('input[name$="[fid]"]').val();`

Comment: I think you are also missing a closing `span` tag.

Comment: you can use the attribute selector   $('input[name=field_tablica[und][0][fid]]') // matches exactly 'field_tablica[und][0][fid]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to the [Poelinca Dorin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25618178/481422) and Arun P Johny comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zlatin_zlatev/0ubg7m34/

The difference is that I do not rely that much on the current DOM structure - it only needs to have a wrapping div with class image-widget-data.

It does not matter if the hidden inputs are directly bellow it, or in some other html dom element - e.g. form.

EDIT: Seems that .closest() has better performance than .parentsUntil(), so better go with it http://jsperf.com/closest-vs-parentsuntil (My answer has become the same as what Arun P Johny suggested after replacing parentsUntil with closest)

```
(function ($) {
$('.picmonkey').on('click', function (e) {
    alert($(this).closest('.image-widget-data').find('input[name$="[fid]"]').val());
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ends with jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) like in [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/x71jme3e/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.picmonkey').on('click', function (e) {
        alert($(this).closest('.imageeditor').siblings('input[name$="[fid]"]').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("[data-codename]").on("click", function() {
    console.log($("[name*=\\[fid\\]]").val())
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/aer9bmrn/2/